# Dynamic Recipient using Grafana Slack Contact Point

Tags: grafana, slack, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

I have a Grafana question. I have multiple alerts set up based on different services.

Each service has its own dedicated slack channel. I want an alert to trigger a slack notification and dynamically have the recipient (slack channel) to be chosen. I don't want to create a new contact point for each alert.

Can someone confirm if this is possible? It doesn't seem like the Grafana slack contact point recipients can be templated. I'm trying to use Labels as the dynamic variable.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @fixnode? I'd like to do exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t access `$labels`, instead you have to reference `.CommonLabels` e.g., `{{ .CommonLabels.ChannelName }}`